# Python create an event to an ObjectListView check box

Tags: python, events, wxpython, objectlistview

How would I create an event for when a box is checked/unchecked?  For this example I just want it to print the data about the object that was checked

NOTE: This code was modified from http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/ as a learning exercise

```
import wx
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

########################################################################
class Book(object):
    """
    Model of the Book object

    Contains the following attributes:
    'ISBN', 'Author', 'Manufacturer', 'Title'
    """
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, title, author, isbn, mfg):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.author = author
        self.mfg = mfg
        self.title = title


########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.products = [Book("wxPython in Action", "Robin Dunn",
                              "1932394621", "Manning"),
                         Book("Hello World", "Warren and Carter Sande",
                              "1933988495", "Manning")
                         ]

        self.dataOlv = ObjectListView(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.setBooks()
        self.dataOlv.CreateCheckStateColumn()        

        # Allow the cell values to be edited when double-clicked
        self.dataOlv.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK

        # create an update button
        updateBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Update OLV")
        updateBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateControl)

        # Create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainSizer.Add(self.dataOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(updateBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateControl(self, event):
        """

        """
        print "updating..."
        product_dict = [Book("Core Python Programming", "Wesley Chun",
                         "0132269937", "Prentice Hall"),
                        Book("Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner",
                         "Michael Dawson", "1598631128", "Course Technology"),
                        Book("Learning Python", "Mark Lutz",
                         "0596513984", "O'Reilly")
                        ]
        data = self.products + product_dict
        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(data)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setBooks(self, data=None):
        self.dataOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 220, "title"),
            ColumnDefn("Author", "left", 200, "author"),
            ColumnDefn("ISBN", "right", 100, "isbn"),
            ColumnDefn("Mfg", "left", 180, "mfg")
        ])

        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(self.products)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,
                          title="ObjectListView Demo", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)

########################################################################
class GenApp(wx.App):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnInit(self):
        # create frame here
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show()
        return True

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """
    Run the demo
    """
    app = GenApp()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `ObjectListView` does not seem to contain that functionality. After digging in the code for a while I have decided to extend it.

You can derive your own class from `ObjectListView` and force the event in. You have to override `_HandleLeftDownOnImage` and `SetCheckState` methods. Or you can just change the ObjectListView code if you like. I have derived a new class:

```
import  wx.lib.newevent

OvlCheckEvent, EVT_OVL_CHECK_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyOvl(ObjectListView):  
    def SetCheckState(self, modelObject, state):
        """
        This is the same code, just added the event inside
        """
        if self.checkStateColumn is None:
            return None
        else:
            r = self.checkStateColumn.SetCheckState(modelObject, state)

            # Just added the event here ===================================
            e = OvlCheckEvent(object=modelObject, value=state)
            wx.PostEvent(self, e)
            # =============================================================

            return r

    def _HandleLeftDownOnImage(self, rowIndex, subItemIndex):
        """
        This is the same code, just added the event inside
        """
        column = self.columns[subItemIndex]
        if not column.HasCheckState():
            return

        self._PossibleFinishCellEdit()
        modelObject = self.GetObjectAt(rowIndex)
        if modelObject is not None:
            column.SetCheckState(modelObject, not column.GetCheckState(modelObject))

            # Just added the event here ===================================
            e = OvlCheckEvent(object=modelObject, value=column.GetCheckState(modelObject))
            wx.PostEvent(self, e)
            # =============================================================

            self.RefreshIndex(rowIndex, modelObject)
```

Then I used that class instead of `ObjectListView`:

```
self.dataOlv = MyOvl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
```

Bound the event:

```
self.dataOlv.Bind(EVT_OVL_CHECK_EVENT, self.HandleCheckbox)
```

And wrote the handler:

```
def HandleCheckbox(self, e):
    print(e.object.title, e.value)
```

I am certain that this is not the best way how to do it, but it is simple and effective hack :-D.

---

**Edit:** Complete example

```
import wx
import  wx.lib.newevent
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn, OLVEvent

OvlCheckEvent, EVT_OVL_CHECK_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyOvl(ObjectListView):  
    def SetCheckState(self, modelObject, state):
        """
        This is the same code, just added the event inside
        """
        if self.checkStateColumn is None:
            return None
        else:
            r = self.checkStateColumn.SetCheckState(modelObject, state)

            # Just added the event here ===================================
            e = OvlCheckEvent(object=modelObject, value=state)
            wx.PostEvent(self, e)
            # =============================================================

            return r

    def _HandleLeftDownOnImage(self, rowIndex, subItemIndex):
        """
        This is the same code, just added the event inside
        """
        column = self.columns[subItemIndex]
        if not column.HasCheckState():
            return

        self._PossibleFinishCellEdit()
        modelObject = self.GetObjectAt(rowIndex)
        if modelObject is not None:
            column.SetCheckState(modelObject, not column.GetCheckState(modelObject))

            # Just added the event here ===================================
            e = OvlCheckEvent(object=modelObject, value=column.GetCheckState(modelObject))
            wx.PostEvent(self, e)
            # =============================================================

            self.RefreshIndex(rowIndex, modelObject)

########################################################################
class Book(object):
    """
    Model of the Book object

    Contains the following attributes:
    'ISBN', 'Author', 'Manufacturer', 'Title'
    """
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, title, author, isbn, mfg):
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.author = author
        self.mfg = mfg
        self.title = title

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.products = [Book("wxPython in Action", "Robin Dunn",
                              "1932394621", "Manning"),
                         Book("Hello World", "Warren and Carter Sande",
                              "1933988495", "Manning")
                         ]

        self.dataOlv = MyOvl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.setBooks()
        self.dataOlv.CreateCheckStateColumn()
        self.dataOlv.Bind(EVT_OVL_CHECK_EVENT, self.HandleCheckbox)

        # Allow the cell values to be edited when double-clicked
        self.dataOlv.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_SINGLECLICK

        # create an update button
        updateBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Update OLV")
        updateBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updateControl)

        # Create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        mainSizer.Add(self.dataOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(updateBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    def HandleCheckbox(self, e):
        print(e.object.title, e.value)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def updateControl(self, event):
        """

        """
        print "updating..."
        product_dict = [Book("Core Python Programming", "Wesley Chun",
                         "0132269937", "Prentice Hall"),
                        Book("Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner",
                         "Michael Dawson", "1598631128", "Course Technology"),
                        Book("Learning Python", "Mark Lutz",
                         "0596513984", "O'Reilly")
                        ]
        data = self.products + product_dict
        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(data)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setBooks(self, data=None):
        self.dataOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 220, "title"),
            ColumnDefn("Author", "left", 200, "author"),
            ColumnDefn("ISBN", "right", 100, "isbn"),
            ColumnDefn("Mfg", "left", 180, "mfg")
        ])

        self.dataOlv.SetObjects(self.products)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,
                          title="ObjectListView Demo", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)

########################################################################
class GenApp(wx.App):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnInit(self):
        # create frame here
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show()
        return True

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """
    Run the demo
    """
    app = GenApp()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Im a very basic/new level of user.  Can you show me how I would apply your solution w/ the example above?

Comment: @ccwhite1 - Added complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectListView documentation doesn't seem to have any data on this subject besides the following two listings:

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/recipes.html#data-based-checkboxes

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/recipes.html#how-do-i-use-checkboxes-in-my-objectlistview

The first one might help you via the checkStateGetter parameter. I suspect that ObjectListView has the CheckListCtrlMixin included in it. If so, then you could subclass your ObjectListView class and override the OnCheckItem method, as shown in the wxPython demo for the CheckListCtrlMixin.

The last thought I had is that you might have to do an adhoc event binding when you select the row. What I mean is, in the selection event for the row, try to get the event object (hopefully a ListItem instance) and bind that object to EVT_CHECKBOX.

If none of those work, then head on over to the official wxPython mailing list and ask there. That's where the majority of wxPython users are.